# Bounding Box for a string in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, gdi+

I have a string with me and I wanted to find the size of box that is bounding the string.Is there any C++ API which can help me with it?
I know it can be done with GDI+.But I wanted a more better way using basic APIs
Using Gdi+ is an overhead as it would have to start Gdi+ and close it..So if i can obtain it directly without using GDI+

Comment: That would require a graphics api, are you using a graphics api?

Comment: At Present I can USe GDI+ is there any other way?

Comment: [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Or [`DrawText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) + `DT_CALRECT`

Comment: Questions asking for *"a more better way"* should be automatically deleted, considering that not a single one of those questions provide a definition for what is considered *good*, or why the existing solution - if any - is not *good enough*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lowest level function that one can think of is GetTextExtentPoint32 in Win32/GDI (C/C++ API).

Comment: We use windows 64.so for that?

Comment: Win32 is a synonym for what many people call the WinAPI. The 32 in that case doesn't denote what bitness it will run on. Usage of the term WinAPI instead of Win32 was meant to remove some of that confusion. Win32(or WinAPI) functions are callable from 64bit windows applications. Win32 got its name when we went from 16bit Windows to 32bit Windows.

Comment: It uses GDI+ .I thought if there can be some mathematical calculation which can give me the output

Comment: GDI is not GDI+. You can't do the computation yourself, it depends on the individual sizes of the characters in the font. Or maybe you want `Width ~ Average Character Width x Character Count` ?

Comment: Don't do that, it's doesn't account for a string made of many small characters, nor kerning and all these kind of stuff. Plus, what happens if the string contains a newline? Over-simplification will lead to bad results sooner than later.

Comment: How can i set the font size..presently it gives me a small size of bounding box?

Comment: The font size is that of the font selected into the HDC you pass